# Hidden Iframe refresh issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, iframe

I have hidden an iframe that refreshes in the background ever minute to keep the token from expiring. The problem I have is when the refresh happen that browser window takes the focus. So if you are doing anything else, that browser will come to the take. Is there any way to stop that from happening? \

Here is the code:

```
<iframe Id="hidden" src="https://xxxxxx.com" style="width:0;height:-1;border:0; border:none;display:none;" onload="refresh()"></iframe>
<iframe Id="hidden2" src="https://xxxxxx.com" style="width:0;height:-1;border:0; border:none;display:none;" onload="refresh()"></iframe>
<script>
function refresh(){
setTimeout(refreshCookie, 30000);
function refreshCookie(){
document.getElementById('hidden').src = document.getElementById('hidden').src;
document.getElementById('hidden2').src = document.getElementById('hidden2').src;
};
};
</script>
```

Comment: This might be browser-specific behavior. Interesting question...

Comment: Have you tested this in multiple browsers?

Comment: Sorry I should have added that this only happens in IE or Firefox but It is a requirement that it is run in IE.

Comment: on windows 10 and IE11 this does not happen. If I understood correctly, I created a page with an input field, reduced the timeout to 3 seconds and I continue to write in the input field with no pronlem..... Could you create a demo....